# cant center image in magento catalog

Tags: css, image, magento, center

i have magneto store with custom template; and i increased size of catalog image; after that images shifted to left and i could not center it
please inspect any image from this link :
http://www.sajidat.com/topsandsweaters.html
i tried to add this

```css
text-align: center;

and

margin: 0px auto;
```

how can i center images and keep image compatible with responsive rules?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us a minimal example of code?

Comment: .products-grid li.last{ margin-right:0;}
.products-grid li.first {} 
.products-grid .product-image { 
 display:block;
 background:#f9f9f9;
 padding:1px;
 max-width:700px; 
 height:auto; 
 margin:5px auto 14px; 
 text-align: center; 
 position: relative; 
 overflow: hidden;